# How to load SurfaceView in a Fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, surfaceview

I am playing a Video in a Activity class in my application, its working good. I am doing it in this way

```
PreLoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
```

And writing code for playing the video in

```
public void playVideoStream(final SurfaceHolder holderRef)
{
    Log.v("act 1","log 1<======");
    try
    {
        //new Thread(new Runnable() {
            //public void run()
                // {
                Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getActivity().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.xyz);
                Log.v("act 2","log 2<======");
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(),video,holderRef);
                Log.v("act 3","log 3<======");
                //mediaPlayer.setDisplay(holderRef);
                Log.v("act 4","log 4<======");
                //Get the dimensions of the video
                int videoWidth = mediaPlayer.getVideoWidth();
                int videoHeight = mediaPlayer.getVideoHeight();
                //Get the width of the screen
                int screenWidth = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
                //Get the SurfaceView layout parameters
                android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = surfaceView.getLayoutParams();
                //Start video
                mediaPlayer.start();
                mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
            //}
        //});
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

I have implemented BottomBar for my application recently, and moved the codebase for playing the video from Activity to Fragment, and this is how my code looks like now

```
public class HomeTabFragment extends Fragment implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
```

and calling the same method on button click and surfaceCreated method without any luck

Its not displaying the video can any one help me on this please

Comment: Have you checked the LogCat? And are you following some tutorial?

Comment: iam getting 
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The surface has been released

Comment: Update your question will full LogCat